# SDO_UTIL.TO_GMLGEOMETRY throws srsname which starts with SDO: in stead of expected EPSG:

Tags: oracle, geometry, gml

We have code which creates a wfs request in the program which is called to get some data from open data. In this code we use oracle procedure SDO_UTIL.TO_GMLGEOMTERY to complete request with necessary gml data.

used query is something like:

```
select 
sdo_util.to_gmlgeometry(geom)
from geom_table;
```

Result should be something like:

```
<gml:Polygon srsName="EPSG:28992" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
        <gml:LinearRing>
            <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">185610.0,320243.0 185620.0,320243.0 185620.0,320233.0 185610.0,320233.0 185610.0,320243.0 </gml:coordinates>
        </gml:LinearRing>
    </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
</gml:Polygon>
```

However, in some cases srsname in result is thrown as "SDO:28992" in stead of "EPSG:28992".

Does anyone know how to make sure srsname is returned as EPSG?